# The method getNumColumns() is undefined for the type GridView

Tags: android, gridview

```
if (getAbsListView() instanceof GridView && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                delay += getAnimationDelayMillis() * ((mLastAnimatedPosition + 1) % ((GridView) getAbsListView()).getNumColumns());
            }
```

The method getNumColumns() is undefined for the type GridView

Manifest Settings:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

getNumColumns() is available for GridView from API 11 So you either change your minSdkVersion or create a custom GridView' with it's API 11 functionality that fits with what's available in API 8.

Comment: At the build time compiler will look for the manifest and see the minSdkVersion as 8 and it will not go on for looking into Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11

Comment: Problem was with Build Target not minSdkVersion ... Thanks